# Can't serialize object in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object but I can't because it has foreign keys pointed to it. I have a table/model named "SERVICO" and a table/model named "SERVICO_PROCESSAMENTO" with a foreign key to "SERVICO". If my object has no foreign key pointed to it, I can serialize it normally. When I have a "SERVICO" object but it has foreign keys pointed, the object has no longer the type "SERVICO", it has the type "SERVICO_(many characters)". If I delete his children before serialize it then it works but I don't want to delete them. Does anyone know how can I serialize without deleting the children?

My code below:

```
public XRetornConv GravaDadosBanco<T>(object currentObject, object previousObject, string _table, string _owner, string _operation, string _procedureCustom)
{
    XmlConverter xmlConv = new XmlConverter();
    string currentXml = "";

    if (previousObject != null)
    {
        previousXml = xmlConv.SerializeClass<T>(previousObject, _table, _owner, _operation, _procedureCustom);
    }
    var currentXml = xmlConv.SerializeClass<T>(currentObject, _table, _owner, _operation, _procedureCustom);

    return new XRetornConv(globaisRep.GravarDadosXML(currentXml, previousXml));
}

public string SerializeClass<T>(object objeto, string _table, string _owner, string _operation, string _procedureCustom)
{
    XmlSerializer<T> xSerializer = new XmlSerializer<T>();

    var serializ = xSerializer.Serialize((T)objeto); //Can't serialize here!

    return ConvertXMLOracle(serializ, _table, _owner, _operation, _procedureCustom);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you take the object to save as an Object in your generic methods... surely this should be T?

Comment: This is not my code actually. I need to change the Entity type of the object to serialize.

Comment: Have you tried to use attribute [XmlIgnore]?

Comment: I haven't tried [XmlIgnore] yet. How do I use it? Go to SERVICO_PROCESSAMENTO model and put it above the attribute?

Comment: Use it to field/properties you don't want to serialize

Comment: Didn't work. When I try to serialize I checked the value of the object and it is "{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SERVICO_3C3693FBBFADB696507409580B3BBC0FF7A7EEE166048B94925351D1412C602C} object {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SERVICO_3C3693FBBFADB696507409580B3BBC0FF7A7EEE166048B94925351D1412C602C}
"

Comment: It should be "(Project name).Data.Service.Model.SERVICO". These objects are stores in a DB. When I'm creating a new object then it has no foreing keys to it then it works. Now when I'm editing/deleting any object that probably has foreign keys pointing then I have this problem. If the object has no foreign keys pointing then I can edit/delete.

Comment: Do you use EF? Because if you do it seems that you get dynamic proxies. You can disable proxy generation by setting ProxyCreationEnabled to false. Note that it will change EF related behaviors.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh... You probably don't want to serialize the Entity Framework objects.... Why don't you just map them to DTOs and serialize them instead? Regardless of whether this is your code, you should really refactor to create a persistence wrapper, as this approach is not very extensible...

Comment: Thank you @Pawel for the help!

Comment: Thank you @Milney for the tip and help!

Comment: Thank you @daniell89 for the tip!